# Zenject Mono Installer not called in Scene tests under some circumstances

Tags: unity-game-engine, testing, zenject

I have a "Main" scene consisting of a `softozor` game object which is controlled by the player. It's a flappy dinosaur. As a child of that `softozor` game object, I have setup another game object, `Installer`, consisting of a Transform component and a `PlayerInstaller (Script)` component:

[image]

The `PlayerInstaller` installs everything necessary for my player's logic. Finally, in the `softozor` game object, I have added a `Game Object Context (Script)` where I register the `PlayerInstaller`:

[image]

In addition to the `softozor` game object, I have also defined a `SceneContext`:

[image]

You'll notice that all installers lists are empty in that `SceneContext`. However, without that `SceneContext` registering nothing, the `PlayerInstaller`  is not triggered. Playing the game with that setup works perfectly well, i.e. the `PlayerInstaller` is called and I can control my dinosaur to do whatever I want in my game.

So far, so good. Now, consider the following Scene Test:

```
public class PlayerTests : SceneTestFixture
{
  [Inject]
  private IPlayer _player;

  [UnityTest]
  public IEnumerator TestScene()
  {
    yield return LoadScene("Main");

    _player.Flap();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
    [...]
  }
}
```

In that test, the `_player` member variable is not injected with an object satisfying the `IPlayer` contract. In fact, the `PlayerInstaller.InstallBindings()` is not called.

If I, instead, get rid of the `Game Object Context (Script)` component in my `softozor` game object, and register the `PlayerInstaller` in the `SceneContext`:

[image]

then I can play the game too, as before, and my test is running, i.e. the `PlayerInstaller.InstallBindings()` method is called during my Scene Test.

What is wrong with my first attempt where I register the `PlayerInstaller` in the `softozor` game object context?

I am working with

- Zenject ver. 7.3.1
- Unity 2019.1.8f1 PC, Mac & Linux Standalone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two containers, the `SceneContext` and a `GameObjectContext`.

I think what happens here is that **they both get installed, but your `GameObjectContext` is not added to the `SceneContext`** -- it worked until the `SceneContext` actually needed to know about the `GameObjectContext` (which was the case in your scene test).

It's difficult to give more precise directions not knowing what is `IPlayer` and what you expect to be injected there, but it makes sense that it's not injected in your `SceneContext`, but only in your `GameObjectContext`.

By putting the `PlayerInstaller` in the `SceneContext`'s MonoInstallers list, you technically solved that problem, but that's clearly not what you want since it makes the sub-container useless and breaks any kind of separation you were going for.

Instead, **you need to interface both contexts using a façade**: [Sub-containers and Facades: Using GameObjectContexts](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject/blob/master/Documentation/SubContainers.md#using-game-object-contexts) *(the explanation consists of an example, so it doesn't make sense for me to quote parts of it, but it's detailed and helpful)*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to hugo, I'm starting to understand how to make it run. My current game components setup is as follows:

[image: UML diagram]

My `PlayerInstaller` is defined like this:

```cs
public class PlayerInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
  [SerializeField]
  Settings _settings;

  public override void InstallBindings()
  {
    Container.BindInterfacesTo<Softozor>()
      .AsSingle()
      .WithArguments(_settings.Rigidbody);
    Container.BindInterfacesTo<InputController>().AsSingle();
    Container.Bind<InputState>().AsSingle();
    Container.BindInterfacesTo<PlayerInputHandler>().AsSingle();
    Container.BindInterfacesTo<PlayerMoveHandler>().AsSingle();
  }

  [Serializable]
  public class Settings
  {
    public Rigidbody2D Rigidbody;
  }
}
```

After reading the documentation advised by hugo, I checked which contexts are created during my scene tests. I was able to see that the method `PlayerInstaller.InstallBindings` was called in my scene tests. In addition, my `Softozor` object implementing the `IPlayer` interface was also injected into the `PlayerMoveHandler` class. That means that the `Game Object Context` was successfully built during the scene tests. The objects registered in that context are, however, not available from the `Scene Context`, which is the one I can access to in my Scene Tests. I naively assumed that whatever I would register in my Game Object Context could be retrieved in my Scene Test. It is apparent, however, that I can only access objects registered in the Scene Context.

At that point, if I really want to access the instance implementing `IPlayer`, I have one alternative: either I create a facade on the `softozor` game object and make the `IPlayer` publicly available on it, or I find a way to resolve instances from the Game Object Context. Is the latter possible at all?

In the end, I think I will redesign my scene test in such a way that I don't need access to the instance of type `IPlayer`, which is totally possible in my case. But I would be curious to know whether or not it's possible to resolve an object from the Game Object Context in a Scene Test. How do I do that?